# How to resolve task scheduler "Run whether user logged in or not" issue

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-task-scheduler

I have been trying to use "dfsvc.exe" from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" folder to resolve a click once issue I am facing. So I have found solution and use this "dfsvc.exe" to run in a schedule in "Task Scheduler".

I am facing issue that, this "dfsvc.exe" run perfectly when I select "Run when user is logged in"
but as soon as I select "Run whether user logged in or not" then it's stop working.

So I found that, when I select "Run whether user logged in or not" it requires "SYSTEM" to access full permission but "SYSTEM" has only 2 "Read" and "Read & Execute" permission, but it's not sufficient to run the "dfsvc.exe".

So I want to know How to give permission to "SYSTEM" to full permission for  folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319".

How to run task with "Run whether user logged in or not" selection in Task Scheduler?

I have system Windows Server 2019 Essentials, build 10.0.17763.

Anyone other thought will be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the owner of the folder is TrustedInstaller. So you need to go to Advanced, and change owner to yourself (remember to keep all permissions). After you take ownership you can change permissions for SYSTEM user to FULL.
And please be careful ;)

Printscreens added (sorry I have only polish OS, but translation added).

[CHANGING OWNER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R4LC.jpg)
[CHANGING PERMISSIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hOng.jpg)

Comment: Thanks !! Tried your solution and changed the ownership to SYSTEM but it doesn't work.

Comment: And have you changed permission for SYSTEM? YOu should give FULL CONTROL.

Comment: can't able to change the permission for SYSTEM. Do you have any idea ? All the changed option has grey out(disable).

Comment: Please see the first answer, I Have added print screens from my OS. I just have done the same. Maybe you missed a step?